# Component Composition/Currying/Prebinding in Angular

Tags: angular

I have the following problem in Angular that I cannot get out of my head.
Lets assume there's an Angular `Wizard` component. This wizard component has ~10 Input/Output parameters like `initialStep`, `onSubmit`, `onStepChange`, `currentStep`, `isLoading`, etc.
Now, I need to create 3 pages with wizards. 1st page has step 1, 2nd page has step 2, and 3rd page has steps 1 & 2 & 3. How it looks in markup:

Wizard1:

```
<wizard *ngIf="process" initialStep="0" (onSubmit)="onSubmit()" (onStepChange)="onStepChange($event)" [loading]="loading" infoPaletteText="You cannot submit" title="title1">
    <wizard-step caption="steptitle1">
        <step1-content></step1-content>
    </wizard-step>
</wizard>
```

Wizard 2:

```
<wizard *ngIf="process" initialStep="0" (onSubmit)="onSubmit()" (onStepChange)="onStepChange($event)" [loading]="loading" infoPaletteText="You cannot submit" title="title2">
    <wizard-step caption="steptitle2">
        <step2-content></step2-content>
    </wizard-step>
</wizard>
```

Wizard3:

```
<wizard *ngIf="process" initialStep="0" (onSubmit)="onSubmit()" (onStepChange)="onStepChange($event)" [loading]="loading" infoPaletteText="You cannot submit" title="title3">
    <wizard-step caption="steptitle1">
        <step1-content></step1-content>
    </wizard-step>
    <wizard-step caption="steptitle2">
        <step2-content></step2-content>
    </wizard-step>
    <wizard-step caption="steptitle3">
        <summary></summary>
    </wizard-step>
</wizard>
```

As you can see wizard component definition is absolutely equal for all components. The title is the only volatile parameter. I need some sort of currying or composition where I get new wizard component with 1 parameter and the rest are fixed.

Angular does not encourage inheritance of components and does not inherit templates.  So, regardless what the component is I want to bind wizard's `onSubmit` to `onSubmit` method, `loading` to `loading` variable etc.

How can I fix this in a correct and smart way?

**EDIT**

Inspired by [this article](https://medium.com/@ttemplier/component-composition-in-angular2-part-1-33f50f402906) I decided to try this insane way:

Create interface for static type check:

```
export interface ISurveyAttachable {
    onSubmit(): void;
    onStepChange(event): void;
    loading: boolean;
}
```

Create directive which may only be attached to the wizard component

```
@Directive({
    selector: 'wizard[survey]'
})
export class SurveyWizardDirective implements DoCheck, OnDestroy {

    private subs = [];

    @Input('survey')
    set param(value: ISurveyAttachable) {
        this.attachableComponent = value;
        this.unsibscribe();

        if (!value) return;
        this.subs.push(this.wizardForm.onStepChange.subscribe(value.onStepChange.bind(value)));
        this.subs.push(this.wizardForm.onSubmit.subscribe(value.onSubmit.bind(value)));
    }

    get param() : ISurveyAttachable{
        return this.attachableComponent;
    }

    private attachableComponent: ISurveyAttachable;

    constructor(private wizardForm: WizardComponent) { }

    ngDoCheck(): void {
        if (!this.attachableComponent) {
            return;
        }
        this.wizardForm.loading = this.attachableComponent.loading;
    }

    private unsibscribe() {
        this.subs.forEach((sub) => sub.unsubscribe());
        this.subs = [];
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.unsibscribe();
    }
}
```

Then, I can use directive in this way in the target component:

```
<wizard *ngIf="process" [survey]="this">
<!--steps here-->
</wizard>
```

So, it shows that my idea is doable however it has many drawbacks:

1. Still not clear how to eliminate *ngIf (extend ngIf directive? maybe borrow some code from ngIf?)
2. Passing `this` variable looks ugly. One can attach a directive in @Component declaration. But in this case I loose reference to the `WizardComponent`.
3. Manual data binding... However it looks like a good trade off.

I consider the solution above more like exercise in Angular advanced topics rather than production ready code. However this place where one needs to update the same code in 3 places already caused couple bugs in the past.

Any new ideas are appreciated.

Comment: I don't see the problem, can you elaborate? The way I see it, you only need one type of WizardComponent which you can use on multiple routes if you like. You can pass any changing attributes, eg. the title as route data.

Comment: My problem is on the line `<wizard *ngIf="process" initialStep="0" (onSubmit)="onSubmit()" (onStepChange)="onStepChange($event)" [loading]="loading" infoPaletteText="You cannot submit" title="title3">` it's repeated everywhere. I need to change it in 3 places (or potentially more"